# How to access Microsoft.xrm.sdk in .Net standard libraries

Tags: dynamics-crm, .net-standard-2.0, xrm

Getting various error for multiple approaches. seems not able to import xrm.sdk in other than .Net Framework.

```
 I'm trying to import Microsoft.xrm.sdk in .Net standards. but I couldn't find anything 
 compatible
 (not compatible). I have tried the following reference 
 Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 
 Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk (2015) 
 Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk (2011)


Package import Failed: NU1202: Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.24 is not compatible 
with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.24 
supports: net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2)
Package restore failed.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. The Dynamics 365 SDK requires the full .NET Framework.

On a related note, Microsoft has released an alpha version of the [.NET Core-compatible SDK](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/Announcing-the-net-Core-SDK-for-Common-Data-Service-CDS-External/td-p/470035).